# Create a simple dynamic headline using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have no knowledge of javascript whatsoever.

Could someone write me some simple javascript code to do the following.

lets say you have the following urls:

example.com/form 
example.com/form?v=China 
example.com/form?v=Brazil

Could the code do the following:

if someone arrives on a page without a parameter (ie. /form) then the heading should be:

## Export Your Goods

If some arrives on a page WITH a parameter (eg  /form?v=China) then the heading should be:

## Export Your Goods To {v}

- ie 'Export Your Goods To China'

Many thanks in advance

Comment: why you are not generating the title on server side based on query string?

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter

Comment: Krab. Im unable to access the server. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this `<script>` at the end of the page:

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.search;
    if (url.length) {
        url = url.replace("?v=", "");
        document.getElementById("main_heading").innerHTML = "Export Your Goods To " + url;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("main_heading").innerHTML = "Export Your Goods";
    }
</script>
```

Provided that you have `heading` as follows:

```
<h2 id="main_heading"></h2>
```

Comment: thankyou. does this script have to go at the end of the page? or can it go anywhere?

Comment: @pablowilks You add this `<script>` just before closing of `</body>` tag like: `<script>....</script></body>`

Comment: one problem i have when i do this, is if i use a querey with spaces, such as 'export to china' then I am getting a heading like the following:
export%20to%20china
Is there something that can be added to tackle the white space issue?

many thanks

Comment: @pablowilks You can use JS function `decodeURIComponent()`. See this resource: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you have HTML like

```
<h2>Export Your Goods To <span id="location"></span></h2>
```

Then you can set value with jQuery

```
$("#location").text("testing");
```

To get the value you can use:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = getParameterByName('v');
$("#location").text(value);
```